# How to send array files to other class

Tags: java, arrays

How can i send a files which stored in array to other class?
I have tried this code but isnt working.

```
public class abc {
    ....
    String [] indexFiles = new String[100];

    public abc (){
       indexFiles [0]=image1.txt;
       indexFiles [1]=image1.txt;
       .... 
       draw = new drawing (indexFiles(0)); // I got error in this code
       draw = new drawing (indexFiles.get(0)); // I also tried this code but it give me error as well.       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
indexFiles[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Does your drawing class take an array of strings, or just a single string?

If it takes an array, use this:

```
draw = new drawing(indexFiles);
```

If it takes a single string, use this:

```
draw = new drawing(indexFiles[0]);
```

To access a single value in an array, you use the [] brackets, not parentheses.

Just a side note:  The "get(0)" method is used for collections like ArrayList:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("MyString");
System.out.println(stringList.get(0));
```